# Node, React Native Fetch Blob, S3 Upload invalid signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So I've been staring at this for a while and I can't obviously see anything wrong, I'm grabbing a signedURL from my Lambda and then uploading to it using rn-fetch-blob.

Lambda Code is as follows:

```
export default async (event, context, callback, utils) => {

    const { imageName } = JSON.parse(event.body)  
    console.log('​imageName', imageName)

    // These access keys relate to a user with AdministratorAccess
    utils.AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
        secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXX',
    })

    let s3 = new utils.AWS.S3({ signatureVersion: 'v4' })
    let params = { Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET', Key: imageName, Expires: 60, ContentType: 'image/jpeg' }
    let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)


    callback(null, utils.responder.success({ url.data.url }))
}
```

React native code is as follows:

```
  const uploadImageToS3Endpoint =  (s3Url, imageUrl) => {


    var source = imageUrl.replace('file://', '')

    return RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', s3Url, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
           }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(source))
  }
```

I get back(along with a load of other stuff, edited for brevity)

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

I did also try allocating public write to the S3 bucket to prove out it wasn't a permissions issue, still got the same result. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as this should be simple!

EDIT

AWS Response RN Fetch

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>THE_KEY</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20181230T120956Z
20181230/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request
b7b755c6335c0401711fafa241bbd816b5c7ad225c41cc324b0daaac2ee9f587</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>5345073e95a1dd39fa28f0a3c5c7350b2d7da75a5dedf3c2a895fdbd0e354961</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 38 31 32 33 30 54 31 32 30 39 35 36 5a 0a 32 30 31 38 31 32 33 30 2f 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 62 37 62 37 35 35 63 36 33 33 35 63 30 34 30 31 37 31 31 66 61 66 61 32 34 31 62 62 64 38 31 36 62 35 63 37 61 64 32 32 35 63 34 31 63 63 33 32 34 62 30 64 61 61 61 63 32 65 65 39 66 35 38 37</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>POST
/C1E2DB45-CB94-4D3C-AEA7-C1CE4B42FCF1.jpg
Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJMVYRTCLXJGL2JGQ%2F20181230%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20181230T120956Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=60&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:tthsshopproductimages.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 4f 53 54 0a 2f 43 31 45 32 44 42 34 35 2d 43 42 39 34 2d 34 44 33 43 2d 41 45 41 37 2d 43 31 43 45 34 42 34 32 46 43 46 31 2e 6a 70 67 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3d 69 6d 61 67 65 25 32 46 6a 70 65 67 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 4a 4d 56 59 52 54 43 4c 58 4a 47 4c 32 4a 47 51 25 32 46 32 30 31 38 31 32 33 30 25 32 46 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 31 38 31 32 33 30 54 31 32 30 39 35 36 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 36 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 74 74 68 73 73 68 6f 70 70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2e 73 33 2e 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>4E4DFD848923AC27</RequestId><HostId>DljdK6KPnzAeXxwUyYu32gb4g4JRI8kDTsdqZVqcM3wLYBsZ6kfT8UGZq6FI5/VimHdY6iL8eKg=</HostId></Error>"
```

Comment: you are getting this signature error on lambda side or on react native ?

Comment: Oh sorry, so yeah it's the response from the RN call.

Comment: can you post the exact response from s3 client and also exact request from rnFetch including headers etc

Comment: Sure give me 20 minutes!

Comment: i have found this interesting information   Note: Not all operation parameters are supported when using pre-signed URLs. Certain parameters, such as SSECustomerKey, ACL, Expires, ContentLength, or Tagging must be provided as headers when sending a request. If you are using pre-signed URLs to upload from a browser and need to use these fields, see createPresignedPost(). can you try using createPresignedPost() instead of getSignedUrl

Comment: Hrmm I can't figure out how to get RN Fetch blob to log out the request object, currently, aws response is above.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Comment: that's why i'm interested in your RNFETCH raw request

Comment: Gotcha let me look into createPresignedPost, although if I remove expiresIn from that above it doesn't make a difference, I'll do some more digging to see if I can get the request object.

Comment: let's try the post method first

Comment: did the above solution  work ?

Comment: No I'm just adding an endpoint to API that logs out the headers that are sent by RN fetch blob

Comment: some users have reported that content length header is required are you including that ?

Comment: Without knowing what Rn fetch blob does under the hood i'm not sure, just raising an issue there now.

Comment: were you able to find request headers, and is it absolutely nessasary to use RNfetch ?

Comment: So RNFetchBlob seems to be way to get files out of the native cache onto an API, I'm just checking alternatives now.

Answer (score 0):

```
      RNFetchBlob.fetch(
            'PUT',
            link,
            {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
            RNFetchBlob.wrap(Platform.OS === "android" ? this.selectedImage.uri : this.selectedImage.uri.replace("file://", "")),
        )
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log("Response data", resp)
                this.onImageUploadSuccess(resp)
            }).catch((err) => {
                this.onUploadFailure(err)
            })
```

This works for me